# How can I check if I can call host() on a URI object in Perl?

Tags: perl, uri

I'm iterating through a list of links on a page, creating a URI object for each.  When the URI object is created, I don't know whether the URL has a scheme, so when I later call `$uri->host()`, I will sometimes get

`Can't locate object method "host" via package "URI::_generic" at -e line 1.`

because the URI object is of type `URI::_generic`, and doesn't have a host() attribute.

I could check before object creation with regex, or I could wrap the `$uri->host()` call in an `eval` block to handle the exception, but I figure there has to be a more suave method than either of those.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My suggestion: use the built in language features to your advantage before a regex.

Instead of a regex, you can do this:

```
if ($uri->can('host')) {
    say "We're good!";
}
```

...to see if it's available.  You could also check it's type:

```
if ($uri->isa('URI::_generic')) {
    die 'A generic type - not good!' ;
}
```

...and verify that you have one that's good.

Comment: I never even knew about the ->can() method for objects, thanks!

Comment: You've got an unmatched ' in your say() call.

Answer (score 4):

The UNIVERSAL class ([perldoc UNIVERSAL](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html)) is pretty useful indeed; it contains:

- `$obj->can( METHOD )`, for determining if METHOD is available on the $obj class (or you can use a bare classname rather than a blessed object - used for [duck typing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duck+typing)!
- `$obj->isa( TYPE )`, for determining if $obj is type TYPE or is descended from TYPE (essentially, checks if ref($obj) is in TYPE's @ISA array) (bare classname also allowed) - used for some polymorphic implementations
- `VERSION`, for getting a module's version string (boorrrrring)